# Complexity of this function

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I have this function

```
int fct (int Y){
        int y = 0 ;
        for ( int i =0; i<Y;++ i ){
            for ( int j=i ; j >=0;--j ){
                y++;
                }
            }
            return y ;
    }
```

I want to know the order of this function, I know that the first for loop its O(n), but I confused to the second for lood, I'm not sure if is O(n).

I think the order of function its O(n^2)

Any help?

Comment: you are correct it is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: This is answered at length at our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) which I'm going to close this as a duplicate of. There are also many examples via [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops].

Comment: 1) What is n? There is none in your code. 2) Have you tried any structured approach? 3) Which "complexity"? That's not a very meaningful notion. Do you mean "$\Theta$-class of its running-time cost function"?